# Vba: delete filtered rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Sheet with columns:

```
Name - Surname - Date - Amount - Ticker
```

**Date** is of the form dd/mm/yyyy while **Ticker** assumes value 0 or 1.
I would like to delete all the rows where date is after 01/01/2000 OR ticker is 0.

I managed to record a macro where I filter and delete filtered rows but it is quite slow. Do you have any idea on how to delete it in a clear way via VBA?

Thanks

Comment: If you are deleting row-by-row it can be quite slow............... **post your current code**

Comment: The fastest way is to use AutoFilter.

Comment: Why you need to do via VBA? Filters or PivotTables could provide you better results.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I know that looping row by row can be slow, I've used the following method with success and not too slowly, but feel free to suggest a better way to do the task at hand, in the meantime, this code will do what you ask, without having to filter anything:

```
Sub foo()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row 'change sheet1 to your sheet if different

For RowCounter = LastRow To 2 Step -1 'loop from second row to the end
    If Sheet1.Cells(RowCounter, 5).Value = 0 Or Sheet1.Cells(RowCounter, 3).Value > "01/01/2000" Then 'check if column 5 equals 0 or column 3 equals 01/01/2000 then
        Sheet1.Rows(RowCounter).EntireRow.Delete 'delete that column
    End If
Next RowCounter 'next row
End Sub
```

Comment: When deleting rows, you have to start with the last one. Also, the OP wanted to catch any date _after_ the one specified.

Comment: Assume, for example that the values `X2, X3, X4` are in rows `2, 3, 4`, respectively. Now assume the macro deletes the row 2. Now the loop will try i=3. However, the value now in row 3 is X4 - X3 got shifted into row 2, and thus X3 never got tested. If you start from the top, several values will escape your test.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, familia. Let me know if you need any more help

```
Sub testy()
    Dim ayy As Long, ayooo As Long
    Dim lmao As Range

    ayy = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For ayooo = ayy To 2 Step -1
        If (Cells(ayooo, 3).Value > 36526) Or (Cells(ayooo, 5).Value = 0) Then Cells(ayooo, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next ayooo

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Two questions 1) is it fine to put >36526 even if it is date format; 2) it is still quite slow (now it's two minutes that is running), any suggestion to make it faster? It's around 150000 rows

Comment: If that's too slow then you'll need to populate a temporary array with the values you want, paste it into a new sheet and delete the old one. Another thing you can do is first sort your values based on _Ticker_, then delete all the rows after it finds the first 0. What I would recommend, however, is just to filter them where `date<36k` and `ticker=1` and copy this to a new table.